# extract all frames of a video without any chroma subsampling

Tags: image, ffmpeg, jpeg

I am looking to extract all frames of a video in jpeg format but in 4:4:4 format i.e. without any chroma sub sampling applied such that MCU is 8x8. I am not sure if there is a way to do this easily but I tried this:

```
`ffmpeg -i Video.mpg Pictures%d.jpg`
```

but this gives me images in 4:2:0 format. Other options is to convert them to RGB and later save it without any subsampling.

Answer (score 0):

video is always encoded in YUV:420 format. Unless its H.264 high profile. so first make sure that input video has YUV 4:4:4